# Add tests on Groovy scripts used in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I have a bunch of groovy scripts that is used by Jenkins. I would like add some tests to these groovy scripts so that any update to groovy scripts i can add test them before merging.

I would like to know what options do we have to write test cases to Groovy scripts. Also how do i execute these tests preferably in ci (gitlab ci) before merging them

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unit test the complete Pipeline using something like [Jenkins Pipeline Unit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit). If you are only interested in Groovy code, you can consider using [Groovy unit testing framework](https://groovy-lang.org/testing.html).

Comment: i was trying the Jenkins Pipeline Unit. Trying to do it but there is a lot of dependencies on gradle and maven, Which i need to understand. But thanks working on that direction.